# iphone development - UIRotationGestureRecognizer (Clockwise & counter Clockwise detection)?

Tags: iphone, gesture

Is there a way to detect if the rotation done by the user is in clockwise or counter clockwise direct???

I searched for that but couldn't find an answer !

My code looks like this:

```
 UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
 recognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(spin)];
 [self.rotating addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
 [recognizer release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `rotation` property will tell you the [rotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in radians.  A negative value would indicate the rotation is clockwise, and a positive value indicates counter-clockwise.

Example:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
recognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(spin:)];  // <-- Note the colon after the method name
[self.rotating addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

- (void)spin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGFloat rotation = gestureRecognizer.rotation;
    if (rotation < 0) {
        // clockwise
    } else {
        // counter-clockwise
    }
}
```

Comment: its actually the other way around.  > 0 clockwise, while < 0 is counter-clock.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version - imagine you've connected your UIRotationGestureRecognizer to an IBAction and are passing in the UIRotationGestureRecognizer as argument `recognizer`. You could very easily test direction with the following:

```
if recognizer.rotation < 0 {
    print("Negative rotation value means anticlockwise rotation detected")
} else if recognizer.rotation > 0 {
    print("Positive rotation value means clockwise rotation detected")
}
```