# How to develop a "spin the bottle" application

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am making a spin the bottle game. I can't figure out how to make the bottle's spin speed controlled by how fast you swipe your finger. I want it to work like the wheel of fortune, the faster you swipe the faster it spins.

I started to develop with the `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`, but I really don't think it is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey Check [this demo](http://www.walnutlabs.com/blog/?p=9).

You have to calculate `velocity`. Which depends on `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

---

This is also useful link : [iphone development - UIRotationGestureRecognizer (Clockwise & counter Clockwise detection)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390457/iphone-development-uirotationgesturerecognizer-clockwise-counter-clockwise)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! i saw in the simulator, and i think will resolve my problem.

Comment: Let me know if you need any other help

Comment: I'm struggling to make some adjustments
I put the image of the wheel that comes in the demo background and I put the image will rotate in a bottle.
What I wanted was for the bottle pointed to the selected color, but in the code that says what was the selected color is the arrow side.
What I did was change the order of the color vector, but sometimes it's an error saying that the color was selected to the side, even when the bottle is more to one than to another.
Would have a way of doing so that the arrow that says what was the color was walking along the top of the image of the bottle?
thanks

Comment: let me try it another way, another question:

I put a UIStepper in this application, and I need to change the array colorNames every time I change the value of the stepper. 

I think the only way is implementing the function:
-(void) calculateMarkersWithCenter:(CGPoint)wheelCenter 
        arcCount:(int) arcCount //Number of arcs in the wheel
      startPoint:(CGPoint) startPoint;

But i don`t know to do this. 
can u help me?? 
thanks !!

Comment: @FabioSilva : I have used above code for the wheel animation where I do not need to worry about any marker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UIRotationGestureRecognizer, detect the tap events directly using `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

Store the time and position of the touch-start, then when the user ends the touch calculate the distance moved while touching down and divide it by the time taken to get the speed of the finger's movement.

Then rotate your bottle accordingly.