# Increasing speed for spinning effect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uikit, transform

In my iPhone app, I have an image on the screen (UIImageView). I would like to spin it and increase the speed at a fixed rate. Basically I'm trying to create an effect where it starts to spin slowly and then increases the speed until the spinning is so fast so you cannot see the image anymore (only a fast animation).

I though of using an animation block and changing the rotation property of a transform, but I'm not sure how to control the speed.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595727/how-to-develop-a-spin-the-bottle-application/9595790#9595790 . Check the link in my answer. It will give you basic idea of how to play with velocity.

Comment: The link is for using a gesture, I don't have any gesture attached, I would like to make a fixed animation which is not controlled by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use an animation with the animation curve set to `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn`.  Set the duration to a long interval, perhaps around 5 seconds.  That should accomplish the effect you're looking for.

---

Sample code:

```
CABasicAnimation *spin = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
spin.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50*2*M_PI];
spin.duration = 5.f;
spin.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[imageView.layer addAnimation:spin forKey:@"spinningAnimation"];
```

If you wish to define your own animation curve, look into CAMediaTimingFunction's [`functionWithControlPoints::::`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CAMediaTimingFunction/functionWithControlPoints%3a%3a%3a%3a) method.

Comment: Hi, UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn does not provide the effect I'm looking for. Is there a way to control the actual ease function or supply my own?

Comment: @sudorm-rf : I haven't down-voted you. I know this is the another possible way for animation.